# Function call in an if statement located in a view doesn't terminate

Tags: arrays, swift, function, swiftui

I have this function that opens the camera roll and takes the user's selected image (if one has been chosen). There's another function, imageAdd(), that I made, which essentially mostly adds something to an array. The camera roll and selecting image thing works, but when I try using an if let to verify the UIImage and pass it along to the imageAdd() function, the function goes on in perpetuity and doesn't terminate. I want it to just happen once, and only when the user selects an image.

I've tried using if let tempImage = image, a boolean, and a few other options but it just doesn't work. Alternatively, if I try calling the imageAdd() function in the imagePickerController() function after the if let..., it works, but the imageAdd() function doesn't write to the imgArray observedObject, just its own one, which is worthless.

```
struct bottomButtons: View {
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State var image: UIImage?
    @State private var newImageChosen = false
    @ObservedObject var imgArray = imagesArray()
    @ObservedObject var imgAdded = imageAdded()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        if image != nil
        {
            if let tempImage = image
            {
                imageAdd(imgSource: tempImage, imgArray: imgArray, imgAdded: imgAdded)
                image = nil
            }
        }
        
        return HStack
        {
            // photo choosy button
            Button(action: {
                self.showImagePicker = true
            },
                   label: {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                        ImagePickerView(image: self.$image, showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, newImageChosen: self.$newImageChosen)
                        }
                    
                    
                
            })
            .scaleEffect(3.5)
            .tint(.black)
            .offset(x: -80)
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            },
                   label: {
                    Image(systemName: "camera.aperture")
            })
            .scaleEffect(4)
            .tint(.black)
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            },
                   label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.right")
            })
            .scaleEffect(3.5)
            .tint(.black)
            .offset(x: 80)
            .padding()
            
        }
        .offset(y: 335)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
    }


struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool
    @Binding var newImageChosen: Bool
    @ObservedObject var imgArray = imagesArray()
    @ObservedObject var imgAdded = imageAdded()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        // nothing to update here
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePickerView
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePickerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = image
            }
            parent.showImagePicker = false
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parent.showImagePicker = false
        }
        
    }
}

func imageAdd(imgSource: UIImage, imgArray: imagesArray, imgAdded: imageAdded) {
    
    imgAdded.imgAdded = true

    imgArray.images.append(editableImg(id: imgArray.images.count, imgSrc: imgSource, size: [50, 80], scalar: 1.0))

    imgAdded.addIndex = imgArray.images.endIndex - 1

    imgAdded.imgAdded = false
    
    print("Image Added")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach here is not valid. The result of `body` is an immutable value that may be evaluated many times and must have no side-effects. The existence of `if` statement inside of `body` does not suggest that this is imperative code (i.e. code that is intended to be evaluated step by step). `if` statements inside of a ViewBuilder are interpreted as `_ConditionalView` data structures. (See the [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) documentation for more on that.)

In short, it is not valid to call `imageAdd` inside of `body`. It's not valid to modify `image` inside of `body`. That creates an infinite loop, since every time a `@State` property changes, `body` is reevaluated.

If you want something to happen when the user selects an image, then you need to put that in a modifier related to selecting the image. `body` must never change the state. It can only *respond* to the state.

Comment: Nicely & concisely expressed Rob.  I was struggling to put all that into words!

Comment: I tried fixing it by placing the ImageAdd() call into imagePickerController(), but no matter what I did it wouldn't actually affect the imgArray(ObservableObject (which is a StateObject in the main view function) that I called--just its own version of it. No matter what I did, it seemed that the function and the coordinator class could never actually inherit the imgArray observable object

Comment: I'm not certain what to suggest here without seeing what you're doing (I'm not certain what `imagePickerController()` is in this context). Generally you should have a model object that updates itself with data, and the View should just observe the model object and update itself when the model changes.